# What is the Adjectival form of Tuba

Tags: adjectives, derivational-morphology

If "xylophonic" is the adjectival form of "xylophone", what is the adjectival form of Tuba?

Comment: There are lots of musical instruments that don't have adjectival forms. (Piano, flute, cello...) In fact, I can't offhand come up with a *use* for an adjectival form of a musical instrument.

Comment: I suppose the only use would be to try and describe a novel musical instrument in terms of a more common instrument. "It's clarinet-like in appearance." So adding -like to the end would be about all I could suggest.

Comment: "Tubalike" *is* attested in [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tubalike) and other sources.

Comment: Try "Tubal" for a start

Comment: I move to invent one, such as: tubic, tuboular, tubastic, tubalicious, and tubawesome.

Comment: Tubonic?  As, the *tubonic plague*?

Comment: @Marthaª - I've heard _pianistic_ quite a few times. M-W gives this example sentence: "Wang performed as if she were claiming ownership of some of Prokofiev's pianistic ideas."

Comment: @Alex Miller: How about Sousophonic? If it's in a light or humorous context, Tubacular might come across if you're dead set on the Tuba reference and correctness is less important.

Comment: This would be a better place to ask: http://forums.chisham.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**xylophonic** isn't much of a word in the first place. It just so happens we're familiar with adding the **-ic** suffix to other words (particularly those with Greek roots) such as *homophobe, telephone, myopia.*

We don't normally derive adjectival words for musical instruments at all, so as Snubian points out, if we're lexically forced to come up with one we usually just add the **-like** suffix.

It's my guess many people wouldn't think of **xylophonic** even if they needed the concept in a single word, so I think you'd find **xylophone-like** quite often anyway.

Comment: What about a "tubal ligation"?  Huh, smart guy, huh?

Comment: @Malvolio - When listening to Sousa marches, I have often considered a tubal ligation.

Answer (score 2):

> **tuba-esque**

seems to be fairly common.  (Try google.)

It makes perfect sense, and the slightly comic feel of "-esque" nicely matches the somewhat comic feel of tubas in general.

(I can't stop thinking about Steve Martin's *L.A. Story* now!)

Answer (score 1):

Don't be shy. If it doesn't already exist, coin it! Speaking as a mellophone player "Tubaphonic" sounds great to me (if you're referring to sound rather than appearance - To me, Tuba-esque brings to mind the configuration of the plumbing, which could also be what you want.)

All those great words we now take for granted were new, shiny, and hot off the press once upon a time.

Comment: Surely it's Tuba-licous ?